# Applying like filter to an IQueryable

Tags: asp.net, lambda, iqueryable, asp.net-dynamic-data

I'm trying to write a custom filter for Dynamic data that will allow me to run like type queries on entity columns. For example searching for john on name field to returen johnson, johns etc.

I'm trying to override the `IQueryable GetQueryable(IQueryable source)` method on the `QueryableFilterUserControl` class. To filter my results. Does anyone know the best way of achieving this?

If this were and `IQueryable<T>` it would be easy as I could return the results of a .Where() clause.

There is an `ApplyEqualityFilter(IQueryable  source, string Column.Name, object value)` method on the QueryableFilterUserControl class but this performs a direct comparison.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at my sample here [Five Cool Filters for Dynamic Data 4](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2010/11/five-cool-filters-for-dynamic-data-4.html)

Also not that in both Linq to SQL and Entity Framework Contains is mapped to LIKE '%term%' in SQL.

Comment: The link to your article is still live however the links inside the article are dead. Could you revise your blog post or amend an answer here? I guess this is your post also, there is more information: http://forums.asp.net/t/1620165.aspx?Date+Range+filter+.